# Android apktool rebuild from decompiled smali crashes app

Tags: android, decompiling, apktool

I have an app that I have decompiled using 'apktool d [apk_name]', when I go to build the app with exactly the same smali code, with no changes at all - 'apktool b [apk_folder] -o [apk_name]' it all works fine and the .apk is produced.

I then sign this .apk with jarsigner, and that all works without error.

However when I then install and launch the app on my device, it crashes out with "Unfortunately this app has stopped".

Why would it crash if I've not made any smali code/res/asset changes, is there a way to check signed certs, e.g if not signed by this cert then error, or something along these lines?

Comment: Post your logcat..